# Get element data

Tags: php, jquery, jplayer

I'm trying to get the `data-mp3` element using Jquery from the following button:

```
<button class="jp-play" id="playNum_<?=$counter?>" title="play" role="button" name="jp-play" tabindex="0" data-number="<?=$counter?>" data-mp3="content/mp3/<?=$midiaMP3?>"></button>
```

I've tried to use `.val()` or `.data()` on the following to get this, but it don't work:

```
var data_mp3 = $(data).find('#playNum_'+number).find('data-mp3');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find()` is used to retrieve child elements. To get data attributes use `data()`. Try this:

```
var data_mp3 = $(data).find('#playNum_' + number).data('mp3');
```

Note that the initial `find()` call is redundant as the `id` attribute should be unique within the page, so the following shorter code should work too:

```
var data_mp3 = $('#playNum_' + number).data('mp3');
```